# Slack event API response using python flask

Tags: python, slack-api

I am working with slack event API. I am getting events on the subscribed events. 
But how to send respond using python requests. slack sends the same event back again after few seconds
what json I need to send back to slack as a response to stop getting the same response?
If you know the code, thank you so much in advance :)

```
@flask.route("/slack_webhook")
def slack_webhook():
    print("Slack Webhook.....!!!")

    data = json.loads(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
    if 'challenge' in data:
    return(data['challenge'])

    if data['type'] == 'event_callback':
        response = make_response("", 200)
        response.headers['X-Slack-No-Retry'] = 1
        print("returning response")
        return response

    else:
        slack_event_handler.delay(data)
```

Comment: Please post the existing code.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directly return the status if successfully received required information.

```
return 'HTTP 200 OK'
```

Comment: I am not a Python expert, but I doubt this works as intended. I think this will return a text `HTTP 200 OK`, which is not what you want. It might work if Slack ignores the response content, but some Slack APIs will not. (e.g. Dialogs). Just `return` (with no text) is better, since it returns an empty response. Both `return` should implicitly return a http code 200, which is all you need in your case.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to respond to the request from Slack directly with a `HTTP 200 OK` within 3 seconds. This will happen automatically if your app terminates within that time.

In case you need more processing time you should look into queuing the event for later processing or starting an asynchronous process for the processing.

Here is what is says in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/events-api#receiving_events):

> Your app should respond to the event request with an HTTP 2xx within three seconds. If it does not, we'll consider the event delivery attempt failed. After a failure, we'll retry three times, backing off exponentially.
>
> Maintain a response success rate of at least 5% of events per 60 minutes to prevent automatic disabling.
>
> Respond to events with a HTTP 200 OK as soon as you can. Avoid actually processing and reacting to events within the same process. Implement a queue to handle inbound events after they are received.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I read all the documentation. I need structure of json object need to send with its header and all its parameters.

Comment: Hi @chetantamboli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return {"isBase64Encoded": True, "statusCode": 200, "headers": { }, "body": ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this old topic which didn't provide a proper solution to my problem. With the trial and fail method, I've came up with this:

```
@app.route("/slack_verification", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def slack_verification():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.get_json()
```

And it worked :) The Request URL has been verified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did with FastApi and without other libraries. Much easier than implementing with external packages.

```py
@app.post("/event")
async def event_listener(request: Request):
    payload = await request.json()
    if not request.headers.get('x-slack-retry-num') and (event := payload.get('event')):
        # Your logic
    return payload
```